# How to retrieve a list of all files in the Working Directory

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

Im looking for a way to get a list of all the files within my working directory and they're `FileStatus`.

I have found `repo.RetrieveStatus()` which is perfect, however it does not return unaltered files.

```
    private void GetFilesList()
    {
        //1. Get files in repository
        Repository repo = new Repository(LocalRepo);
        List<File> filelist = new List<File>();
        foreach (var item in repo.RetrieveStatus()) //This only lists altered files
        { 
            filelist.Add(new File(item.FilePath, this, item.State));
        }
        Files = filelist.ToArray<File>();   
    }
```

The only way I can think of doing this is to create two lists, one with all of the files in the directory: `Directory.GetFiles();` -(ListA)

Then compare this to a list created from `RetrieveStatus()` -(ListB). I would then have to *assume* that any files in ListA that aren't in List B are unaltered.

Surely there is a better way to do this?

I've searched through the repository on GitHub and the only issue I can find is  [this one](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/881) and it does not appear to be related.

Is anyone aware of any other methods in the LibGit2Sharp library I can use for this purpose?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an ongoing Pull Request about this exact feature (see **[#863](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/863)**).

Proposed implementation would be to pass a optional boolean to the `StatusOptions`.

```
RepositoryStatus status = repo.RetrieveStatus(
     new StatusOptions() { IncludeUnaltered = true | false });
```

Feel free to subscribe to it in order to be kept updated about its progress (and eventual merge).

Comment: I thought I was going crazy! Thank You